# Keyboard and touch screen not working at all on MS Surface laptop

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, surface

I've just downloaded Ubuntu 18.04 on a flash drive and have gone to install it alongside Windows but my keyboard is not responsive at all. Every time I try to type something in it doesn't work and my touch screen isn't working either.

My computer is a Microsoft surface laptop (1st gen, Intel core i5.) The keyboard is built in.

Comment: What exactly is it for a keyboard?, directly from your Laptop or a Bluetooth keyboard?.

Comment: Will need more information for us to help.  Computer model, cpu and any graphics.  Type of keyboard, built in, wired or wireless.  Edit your question with this info, and someone on here can begin to help you.

Comment: The keyboard is directly from my laptop.

Comment: What is the name of your laptop?.

Comment: It’s a Microsoft surface laptop with Intel core i5